# Dnf removes many dependencies along mariadb-config and mariadb-common

Tags: mariadb, fedora, dnf

Working on Fedora 26. Had mariadb 10.1.26 installed but I need some features available on 10.2.2.

To install MariaDB-server 10.2 from MariaDB repositories, it seems necessary to remove mariadb-config and mariadb-common, since some files are conflicting:

```
# dnf install MariaDB-server
Last metadata expiration check: 0:39:56 ago on Thu 21 Dec 2017 02:25:04 AM CET.
Dependencies resolved.
===================================================================================================================================================================================================================
 Package                                                Arch                                        Version                                                     Repository                                    Size
===================================================================================================================================================================================================================
Installing:
 MariaDB-server                                         x86_64                                      10.2.11-1.fc26                                              mariadb                                       24 M
Installing dependencies:
 MariaDB-client                                         x86_64                                      10.2.11-1.fc26                                              mariadb                                       11 M
 MariaDB-common                                         x86_64                                      10.2.11-1.fc26                                              mariadb                                       79 k
 galera                                                 x86_64                                      25.3.22-1.fc26.fc26                                         mariadb                                      8.9 M
 perl-DBI                                               x86_64                                      1.636-4.fc26                                                fedora                                       732 k
 perl-Math-BigInt                                       noarch                                      1.9998.11-1.fc26                                            fedora                                       193 k
 perl-Math-Complex                                      noarch                                      1.59-395.fc26                                               updates                                      101 k

Transaction Summary
===================================================================================================================================================================================================================
Install  7 Packages

Total size: 45 M
Installed size: 214 M
Is this ok [y/N]: y
Downloading Packages:
[SKIPPED] MariaDB-server-10.2.11-1.fc26.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded                                                                                                                                            
[SKIPPED] perl-DBI-1.636-4.fc26.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded                                                                                                                                                    
[SKIPPED] MariaDB-client-10.2.11-1.fc26.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded                                                                                                                                            
[SKIPPED] MariaDB-common-10.2.11-1.fc26.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded                                                                                                                                            
[SKIPPED] perl-Math-BigInt-1.9998.11-1.fc26.noarch.rpm: Already downloaded                                                                                                                                        
[SKIPPED] galera-25.3.22-1.fc26.fc26.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded                                                                                                                                               
[SKIPPED] perl-Math-Complex-1.59-395.fc26.noarch.rpm: Already downloaded                                                                                                                                          
Running transaction check
Transaction check succeeded.
Running transaction test
Error: Transaction check error:
file /etc/my.cnf from install of MariaDB-common-10.2.11-1.fc26.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mariadb-config-3:10.1.26-2.fc26.x86_64
file /usr/lib64/mysql/plugin/dialog.so from install of MariaDB-common-10.2.11-1.fc26.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mariadb-common-3:10.1.26-2.fc26.x86_64
file /usr/lib64/mysql/plugin/mysql_clear_password.so from install of MariaDB-common-10.2.11-1.fc26.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mariadb-common-3:10.1.26-2.fc26.x86_64
```

If I try to remove the concerned packages mariadb-config and mariadb-common, DNF needs to remove an impressive list of unrelated packages, like shotcut, blender, mplayer. Sample:

```
Removing:
 mariadb-config                                        x86_64                                 3:10.1.26-2.fc26                                               @updates                                        1.3 k
Removing dependent packages:
 OpenImageIO                                           x86_64                                 1.7.17-2.fc26                                                  @updates                                        9.3 M
 armadillo                                             x86_64                                 7.900.1-1.fc26                                                 @fedora                                          47 k
 blender                                               x86_64                                 1:2.79-1.fc26                                                  @updates                                        143 M
 dvdauthor                                             x86_64                                 0.7.2-2.fc26                                                   @fedora                                         609 k
 flowblade                                             noarch                                 1.14-3.gitcad77b5.fc26                                         @unitedrpms                                      20 M
 gdal-libs                                             x86_64                                 2.1.3-1.fc26                                                   @fedora                                          19 M
 gmic                                                  x86_64                                 1.7.2-3.fc26                                                   @fedora                                          14 M
 kdenlive                                              x86_64                                 17.08.3-2.fc26                                                 @unitedrpms                                      59 M
 kf5-kfilemetadata                                     x86_64                                 5.38.0-1.fc26                                                  @updates                                        701 k
 ladspa-calf-plugins                                   x86_64                                 0.0.60-5.fc26                                                  @fedora                                           0  
 lapack                                                x86_64                                 3.6.1-4.fc26                                                   @fedora                                          11 M
 libspatialite                                         x86_64                                 4.3.0a-4.fc26                                                  @fedora                                          11 M
 lives                                                 x86_64                                 2.8.7-1.fc26                                                   @rpmfusion-free                                 8.8 M
 mariadb-common                                        x86_64                                 3:10.1.26-2.fc26                                               @updates                                        393 k
 mariadb-libs                                          x86_64                                 3:10.1.26-2.fc26                                               @updates                                        3.6 M
 mkvtoolnix                                            x86_64                                 17.0.0-1.fc26                                                  @updates
```

Does `mkvtoolnix` really depends on mariadb-config?

```
# dnf deplist mkvtoolnix | grep -i maria
Last metadata expiration check: 0:44:36 ago on Thu 21 Dec 2017 02:25:04 AM CET.
#
```

It seems not... How can I install `MariaDB-server` (with caps = 10.2) without removing unrelated packages (which I actually want to keep and not remove/reinstall)?

Comment: `yum remove MariaDB-server MariaDB-client`, then try again.

Comment: As I said (it's the point of my question), it wants to remove unrelated packages. I don't want to remove thoses packages (list excerpt provided in the question).

Comment: Good luck, welcome to linux xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally succeeded:

- Removed mariadb-* with yumex (GUI)
- Removed mariadb-server with dnf (CLI)
- Installed MariaDB-* (10.2) with dnf

For unknown reason, Yumex did not remove unrelated packages while dnf would have.

Comment: The reason is simple, yumex-dnf doesn't remove "weak dependencies" neither "cascade dependencies" but dnf does. For documentation on "weak dependencies" look into: https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/PackagingDrafts/WeakDependencies

Comment: Thanks for your comment and the link. However, Blender, for instance, is absolutely not related to mariadb-config: mariadb-config is neither a weak or a cascade dependency, it's not a dependency at all...